# A problem with fscanf() in c , overwriting other variables

Tags: c, scanf

I'm traying to read from a file two things :
1- a list of integers(on the top of the file) in to an array of integers inputs[]
2- 3 matrixes 5x5 etch into an array of array of array boards[][][]
the firs part works properly but when the 2 part finished some how the inputs[] change values

The code :

```
void loadfile(const char* filepath,int *inputs ,int boards [nboards][size][size]){
    FILE *inp=fopen(filepath,"r");
    //loading the marked numbers
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        fscanf(inp,"%d",inputs+i);
        //to show that inputs reseve the the right values at the start
        printf("%d ",*(inputs+i));
        fseek(inp,ftell(inp)+1,SEEK_SET);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //loaing the boards
    for(int n=1;n<=nboards;n++){
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                fscanf(inp,"%d",&boards[n][i][j]);
                printf("%d ",boards[n][i][j]);
                }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(inp);
}  
int main(){
    
    int inputs[4]={};
    int boards[nboards][size][size]={};
    loadfile("inputs.txt",inputs,boards);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        printf("%d ",*(inputs+i));
}
```

The file :

```
 7,4,9,5

22 13 17 11  0
 8  2 23  4 24
21  9 14 16  7
 6 10  3 18  5
 1 12 20 15 19

 3 15  0  2 22
 9 18 13 17  5
19  8  7 25 23
20 11 10 24  4
14 21 16 12  6

14 21 17 24  4
10 16 15  9 19
18  8 23 26 20
22 11 13  6  5
 2  0 12  3  7
```

The output:

```
7 4 9 5
22 13 17 11 0 8 2 23 4 24 21 9 14 16 7 6 10 3 18 5 1 12 20 15 19
3 15 0 2 22 9 18 13 17 5 19 8 7 25 23 20 11 10 24 4 14 21 16 12 6
14 21 17 24 4 10 16 15 9 19 18 8 23 26 20 22 11 13 6 5 2 0 12 3 7
21 17 24 4
```

Comment: `for(int n=1;n<=nboards;n++)` should be `for(int n=0;n<nboards;n++)`.

Comment: wow ..ty so much i was 2days now . and its simple as that .. :) .ty  so much . it works ..

Comment: If your file has commas between the values, your fscanf format needs commas as wel.

Comment: it help too .. so i can remove the fseek(inp,ftell(inp)+1,SEEK_SET);